# Dynamic Classes in Kivy... I'm still lacking Comprehension.. Doesn't work as I'm Expecting

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

My Py file:

```
    from kivymd.app import MDApp
    from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.video import Video
    

 class MainApp(MDApp):
        def on_start(self):
            # Set colors
            self.theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    
    MainApp().run()
```

So this is my custom widget:

```
<PagesButton@MDRectangleFlatButton>
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
        Line:
            width: 4
            ellipse: (self.x, self.y, 120, 120)

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: None, None
        #pos_hint: {'center': .5, 'top': .5}
        width: 70
        height: 45

    Image:            
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 60, 60
        keep_ratio: False
        allow_stretch: True
```

and here is an instance of said widget im trying to use,

```
        GridLayout:  
            cols: 10
            rows: 1
            size_hint_y:  None
            height: 150
            spacing: 60
            padding: 20, 60, 20, 0


            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    Line:
                        width: 4
                        ellipse: (self.x, self.y, 120, 120)

                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    #pos_hint: {'center': .5, 'top': .5}
                    width: 30
                    height: 25

                    Image:
                        source: "Nav_icons/Events.png"
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: 60, 60
                        keep_ratio: False
                        allow_stretch: True
                        #pos_hint: {'left': .5, 'top': 1.1}


            PagesButton:
                text: 'hey'
```

Now the way I understand it....

if i use the custom dynamic class inside my code, should it not already have all of the other properties that i wrote when i initially defined the class?

In this current example, when i write PagesButton, i only get a regular rectangle button with the text 'hey' in the middle. Everything else i wrote in PagesButton@MDRectangleFlatButton is totally disregarded.

[image]

My intention is to define a broad view class with all of the property definitions, and then use instances of this class over and over, with slight tweaks each time, such as a new image with new source, yet everything else in the broad class would still appear.  In this example, i should be getting a stroked, circular button every single time i use the class, with a new image inside. I expect changes only if i define a new rule to that specific property each instance, otherwise, everything should be visually constant and consistent.

Is this not how its supposed to work? Or am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Post a minimal runnable example. Also the children of your `PagesButton` probably have the default pos of 0, 0 since you didn't specify otherwise.

Comment: the code already works, thats not the point. Im looking for COMPREHENSION on why things are as they are....why do the dynamic classes behave as such. I dont see how my code isn't runnable as posted

Comment: Your code isn't remotely complete. Runnable means in a form so that nothing is missing and it's a valid Python program. That makes it easy for investigators to investigate and debug.

Comment: I just edited it. However, i dont believe the py file is pertinent to what im asking. However, there it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your dynamic class is technically working as you described. The `PagesButton` instance will have children as you defined in your `kv` rule. The problem is that you appear to be making some assumptions that are incorrect. In general, a `Widget` does not control the position or size of its children. Among those that do are the layouts. So the `PagesButton` gets drawn as it should.

From the `Widget` [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html):

- A Widget is not a Layout: it will not change the position or the size of its children. If you want control over positioning or sizing, use a Layout.
- The default size of a widget is (100, 100). This is only changed if the parent is a Layout. For example, if you add a Label inside a Button, the label will not inherit the button’s size or position because the button is not a Layout: it’s just another Widget.

So, since the default `pos` of a `Widget` is `(0,0)`, the children of your `PagesButton` will get drawn at `(0,0)`.

You also cannot use `size_hint` or `pos_hint` for the children of `PagesButton`, since those hints are processed by layouts.

Not sure exactly how you want the `PagesButton` to look, but consider using a `BoxLayout` with a `MDRectangleFlatButton` as one of its children. You can create a dynamic class that extends `BoxLayout` (or any layout) and contains an `Image` and a `MDRectangleFlatButton`.

Comment: well that seems to put me on the right track mostly. However, in testing it right now.... i put image, source: 'image1.png', for PagesButton.... but it doesn't update the image in the same place as where the original would be, nor does it replace it.... basically, i now have 2 images on the screen now instead of just 1 which is supposed to be the replacement. Why is this??

Comment: ok but what do you say in regard to the example of two images at the same time as opposed to replacing the original? Im not quite figuring that out

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are doing in your previous comment. But I'm not sure I can answer any better. These issues are difficult to unravel, and even worse when kivyMD is involved. For example, when you use `Builder`, it loads the default `kv` rules for the widgets from a `style.kv` file. But the kvyMD rules are in each widgets `.py` file, so they don't get loaded until that `.py` is imported. That can cause unexpected differences. If your python code explicitly imports `MDRectangleFlatButton`, your dynamic class will look differently than if you don't have that explicit import.

Comment: If you take a look at my new updated original question, you will see the buttons. The 2nd button is my concern at the moment. In the example, you see a radio icon. In the second picture, you see a radio icon, and a chat icon....HOWEVER, it should only be the chat icon INSTEAD OF the radio icon. As you can see though, it is both icons simultaneously once i used the instance. THIS is what im not understanding.

Comment: The only image source that I see in your code is the `Events,png`. I have no idea how two icons that are not even referenced in your code appear at all. There must be something else going on. That is why we ask for a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.